# What are the api that make spring boot application development fast?

Tags: java

I am looking for API like Apache common, IO, beans-util, and Lombok that make spring boot or java application fast and easy. Need to write less code for particular type of operation.

Could I use Guava API instead of util package. Does it help to do development fast and easy?

Which class is better between StringUtil.java provide by Apache and Spring framework itself? Which one I use from both of them.

Thanks,
Sube

Comment: You can use Guava if you need it. I don't think I've ever had need to use it personally. For the last part, quote from [Springs  SpringUtils docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html): "Mainly for internal use within the framework; consider Apache's Commons Lang for a more comprehensive suite of String utilities."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific set of api, starters are defined for different purposes. So individually no api will make development fast, it is how you set up and related auto configuration.

Spring boot support most of the api we generally use however for any specific need you can customize and configure before using it.

Regarding Apache or Spring, it depends which all utilities methods you need for string manipulation.

Comment: Thank you Niraj for your suggestion. It makes sense.

Comment: Please mark it answered.